# JQuery Clears Input Tag of Password Type. But Show Dots in Browser

Tags: jquery, html, input

I used following JQuery to empty input password field when page is loaded:

```
 $('input[type="password"]').val('');
```

But password input field still show dots in browser.

Also, Chrome debugger does not show any text in the  field. HTML is as following

```
 <input type="password" id="key" name="key">
```

I expect input field is empty before entering password when page is loaded.

What's wrong?

Comment: It's cleared. Why it shows dots? If using text, password will show up when typing?

Comment: If you want clear the field you should wrap your jquery into $(document).ready(function() { ..... })

Comment: The page is already loaded. JQuery clear action is called after that.

Comment: Do the old Ctrl Refresh with DevTools open to make sure there's no lingering weirdness in your cache and report back?

Comment: And also, substitute your code with this: `$("input[type='password']").val('');`

Comment: It seems cache in the browser caused this. I loaded same page from another computer and found password field is empty.